# How to transfer Chrome extension settings from guest to account?

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles

I need to upgrade my Chome but it says I need to reinstall Chrome. I have some extension settings I want to keep but I've been logged in as Guest this entire time. How do I transfer those settings from Guest to my Google account?

Comment: Log in with your Google account?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome default user data is stored at
C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
Copy that folder ("Default") when Google Chrome is closed and then paste it back after reinstalling Chrome

-
(if there are a few profiles, each gets a new folder. for example, "Profile 1" Profile 2" Etc. So in case someone wants to copy a specific user profile, could do the same with that folder)

Answer (score 0):

You will find the settings of an extension in the folder:

```
C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\EXTENSION-ID
```

Install the extension in the main account, then close Chrome and
replace the contents of the extension's folder with those
from the guest account.